# Odoo 10 : Custom module doesn't appear in top black menu after installation

Tags: xml, module, menu, customization, odoo

I created a custom module which menuitems are like this :

```
 <record id="view_sim_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Sim Tree</field>
        <field name="model">simcard.simcard</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="1" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Sim Tree">
                <!-- <button name="open_something" string="Confirmer le pointage" type="object" /> -->
                <!-- <field name="id" /> -->
                <field name="icc" />
                <field name="imsi" />
                <field name="msisdn" />
                <field name="id" />
                <field name="sim_model" />
                <field name="lte_status" />
                <field name="life_cycle_status" />
            </tree>

        </field>
    </record>

 <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="view_sim">
        <field name="name">Sim Details</field>
        <field name="res_model">simcard.simcard</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[]</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Well, Well, Well You can stop!
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>

 <!-- Top menu item -->
        <menuitem id="simcard.menu_root" name="Simcard" sequence="2"  />
        <!-- menu categories -->
        <menuitem id="simcard.sim" name="Sim" parent="simcard.menu_root" action="view_sim" sequence="1" />
```

This module gets installed without any error. But it doesn't appear in the top menu of odoo where all the other modules are accessible. I think its because of the sequence number problem. I tried to change the sequence number but still it doesn't appear in top menu. Anyone has any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create the security access records for the menu actions target models to be associated with existing or custom new groups that you could assign it to the users. That's why you aren't seeing anything

Comment: i tried and i got this error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760293/odoo-10-secure-access-to-custom-module